Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) ADT Set
I have been trying to implement a Set ADT using open addressing for the hash table and lazy deletion, however, I am having problems with the resizing of the Set.
I can insert elements up to 75% of the total capacity of the Set, but when I resize it and try to access all of the elements again (all inserted elements are unique), I get this error:
==294546== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==294546==    at 0x48D6AD6: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1516)
==294546==    by 0x48C079E: printf (printf.c:33)
==294546==    by 0x10FD3D: showDisciplineStatistics (simple.c:149)
==294546==    by 0x109454: main (main.c:37)
==294546==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==294546==    at 0x10FC00: showDisciplineStatistics (simple.c:127)

I know that is has something to do with how the elements are added back to the Set after resize, but I have no idea how to do it properly. In every single iteration I get the error precisely at index 128 and everything after. Here is how I am inserting the elements, v[] is a flag to check for the existence of all elements:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "set.h"

int main() {
  PtSet set = setCreate();

  int v[200];
  for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    setAdd(set, i);
  }

  int elementsSize;
  setSize(set, &elementsSize);
  SetElem *elements = setValues(set);

  for(int i = 0; i < elementsSize; i++) {
    v[elements[i]] = 1;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    printf("%d - %d\n", i, v[i]);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

set.c, SetElem is typed as an integer:
#define LOAD_FACTOR_THRESHOLD 0.75

typedef struct setNode {
  SetElem element; // Element present at this node.
  int occupied; // Whether this node is occupied or not.
  int deleted; // Whether this node has been deleted or not.
} SetNode;

typedef struct setImpl {
  SetNode* nodes; // Nodes of the set.
  int size; // Size of the set.
  int deletedCount; // Number of nodes that have been deleted.
  int index; // Determines the capacity (getPrime(index)) and multiplier (getPrime(index - 1)). 
} SetImpl;

static int hashFunction(SetElem elem, int multiplier, int tableSize);

static bool ensureCapacity(PtSet set);

static int findPosition();

static int getPrime(int index);

PtSet setCreate() {
  PtSet set = (PtSet) malloc(sizeof(SetImpl));
  if(set == NULL) return NULL;
  
  SetNode* newNodes = (SetNode*) calloc(getPrime(1), sizeof(SetNode));
  if(newNodes == NULL) return NULL;

  set->nodes = newNodes;
  set->size = 0;
  set->deletedCount = 0;
  set->index = 1;

  return set;
}

int setAdd(PtSet set, SetElem elem) {
  if(set == NULL) return SET_NULL;

  if(!ensureCapacity(set)) return SET_NO_MEMORY;

  int position = findPosition(set, elem);
  if(position == -1) return SET_ERROR;

  int capacity = getPrime(set->index);
  int firstDeletedIndex = -1;
  bool added = false;
  for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    if(set->nodes[position].occupied == 0 && set->nodes[position].deleted == 0) {
      if(firstDeletedIndex != -1) {
        position = firstDeletedIndex;
        set->deletedCount--;
      }
      set->nodes[position].element = elem;
      set->nodes[position].occupied = 1;
      set->nodes[position].deleted = 0;
      set->size++;
      added = true;
      break;
    }
    if(set->nodes[position].occupied == 1) {
      if(setElemCompare(set->nodes[position].element, elem) == 0) {
        return SET_DUPLICATE;
      }
    }
    if(set->nodes[position].deleted == 1 && firstDeletedIndex == -1) {
      firstDeletedIndex = position;
    }
    position = (position + 1) % capacity;
  }

  if(added == false) return SET_FULL;
  else return SET_OK;
}

int setSize(PtSet set, int *ptSize) {
  if(set == NULL) return SET_NULL;

  *ptSize = set->size;

  return SET_OK;
}

SetElem* setValues(PtSet set) {
  if(set == NULL) return NULL;
  
  SetElem *newValues = (SetElem*) calloc(set->size, sizeof(SetElem));

  int j = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < getPrime(set->index); i++) {
    if(set->nodes[i].occupied == 1) {
      newValues[j++] = set->nodes[i].element;
    }
  }

  return newValues;
}

static int hashFunction(SetElem elem, int multiplier, int tableSize) {
  int len_bytes = sizeof(elem);
  char *byte = (char*)&elem;
  int c, hash = 5381;

  for(int i=0; i < len_bytes; i++) {
    c = *byte++;
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
  }

  return abs((hash * multiplier) % tableSize);
}

static bool ensureCapacity(PtSet set) {
  if(set == NULL) return false;
  
  if((double) (set->size + set->deletedCount) / getPrime(set->index) >= LOAD_FACTOR_THRESHOLD) {
    SetNode *newNodes = (SetNode*) calloc(getPrime(set->index + 1), sizeof(SetNode));
    if(newNodes == NULL) return false;

    int oldElementsSize;
    setSize(set, &oldElementsSize);
    SetElem *oldElements = setValues(set);

    free(set->nodes);
    set->nodes = newNodes;
    set->size = 0;
    set->deletedCount = 0;
    set->index++;

    for(int i = 0; i < oldElementsSize; i++) {
      setAdd(set, oldElements[i]);
    }
    free(oldElements);

    return true;
  }

  return true;
}

static int findPosition(PtSet set, SetElem elem) {
  if(set == NULL) return -1;

  int position = hashFunction(elem, getPrime(set->index - 1), getPrime(set->index));

  return position;
}

static int getPrime(int index) {
  // Useful prime numbers for setting table size.
  int primeTable[] = {
    53, 107, 193, 389, 769, 1543, 3079, 6151, 12289, 24593,
    49157, 98317, 196613, 393241, 786433, 1572869, 3145739, 6291469, 12582917,
    25165843, 50331653, 100663319, 201326611, 402653189, 805306457, 1610612741
  };
  int primeSize = sizeof(primeTable) / sizeof(int);

  if(index >= primeSize) return -1;
  else return primeTable[index];
}

set.h:
#define SET_OK 0
#define SET_NULL 1 
#define SET_NO_MEMORY   2
#define SET_EMPTY 3
#define SET_FULL 4
#define SET_ERROR 5
#define SET_DUPLICATE 6

#include "setElem.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

/** Forward declaration of the data structure. */
struct setImpl;

/** Definition of pointer to the  data stucture. */
typedef struct setImpl *PtSet;

/**
 * @brief Creates a new empty set.
 * 
 * @return PtSet pointer to allocated data structure, or
 * @return NULL if unsufficient memory for allocation.
 */
PtSet setCreate();

/**
 * @brief Add an element to the set. If it already exists, then silently replace it.
 * 
 * @param set [in] pointer to the set.
 * @param elem [in] element to add.
 * 
 * @return SET_OK if successful, or
 * @return SET_FULL if no capacity available, or
 * @return SET_NO_MEMORY if unsufficient memory for allocation, or
 * @return SET_NULL if 'set' is NULL.
 */
int setAdd(PtSet set, SetElem elem);

/**
 * @brief Gets the size of the set.
 * 
 * @param set [in] pointer to the set.
 * @param ptSize [out] size of the set.
 * 
 * @return SET_OK if successful, or
 * @return SET_FULL if no capacity available, or
 * @return SET_NO_MEMORY if unsufficient memory for allocation, or
 * @return SET_NULL if 'set' is NULL.
 */
int setSize(PtSet set, int *ptSize);

/**
 * @brief Gets the values from a given set. 
 *
 * The size of the dynamic array will be the size of the set.
 * 
 * @param set [in] pointer to the set.
 * 
 * @return array containing the values of the set, or
 * @return NULL if the 'set' is empty or NULL
 */
SetElem* setValues(PtSet set);

setElemCompare() and setElemPrint():
void setElemPrint(SetElem elem) {
  printf("%d\n", elem);
}

int setElemCompare(SetElem elem1, SetElem elem2) {
  if(elem1 == elem2) return true;
  else return false;
}

Valgrind settings:
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes ./prog

I really have no idea what's going on, I have been at it for longer than I would like to admit and can't seem to resize the hash table properly.

Remember that uninitialized local variables, including arrays, really are uninitialized. You don't initialize the array v, and the loop for(int i = 0; i < elementsSize; i++) could leave elements of v uninitialized and with an indeterminate value. Which you then print. Properly initialize the array first, as in int v[200] = { 0 }; to fix this.

The Valgrind messages give you some specific guidance about what code to analyze: file simple.c on and around lines 127 and 149.  How about presenting those? Additionally, that particular Valgrind message coming from printf() is suggestive of an attempt to print data as a string that is either altogether uninitialized or is missing a string terminator.

Yes but the values should be initialized when the setAdd adds all of the elements up to 200 to the set. Because even if I do v[200] = {0} every single element after 128 is 0, which is false since they were added to the set.

Lines 127 to 149 is the creation and insertion in the set I have shown above.

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Have you checked the value of elementsSize? Have you checked that all the values of elements cover all elements of v? Have you created proper unit-testing of your set functions to make sure they work as you expect them to?

And more importantly, if you explicitly initialize the array v, does it work? Do you still get the same warning?

You're asking for our help.  Please don't make that hard on us.  If the code on and around lines 127 and 149 of file simple.c is among that already presented then please edit the question to point them out.  However, I am inclined to think that they are not already there, because Valgrind reports them appearing inside a function named showDisciplineStatistics(), which does not seem to be present.

I have edited the question, the rest of simple.c are other data processing functions with other data sets. showDisciplineStatistics() only has what I have put on main now.

I don't get the warning anymore but it's still not the expected behavior, the set should fill up all the way to 200, it goes to size 128 and stops.

When I print the value of the size of the set it also only gives me 128. The expected answer is 200.

@hrodric That means your set functions does not work as you expect. You need to test them in isolation from the rest of your program. I recommend you create a brand new program, starting with an empty main function. Build with extra warnings enabled, treated as errors. When building cleanly, test. Then add a very small part of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Build and test as before. If (when) you get a problem, it's much easier to isolate it for debugging and fixing.

Also, many of the set functions returns an error/success indicator. You never seem to check that your calls to them actually succeed?

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

typedef struct setImpl *PtSet; You will want to review: Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?. That's not saying you can't do it, you just need to be careful and think about who else may use your code. Also ensureCapacity() resets the size and deletedcount zero - may be okay, seems like you want the prior counts. Also, using -1 as a starting reference is awkward in cases where index may be zero, e.g. getPrime(set->index - 1) -- bad things can happen.

I voted to close as "simple typo" since you found the problem yourself and in this case it is a "typo" not useful for future readers. The post already had 2 old close votes for "needs debugging details" however, so that is the close reason displayed. But you don't need to do anything or clarify anything further.

I have fixed it, I don't know what's wrong with me, in the setAdd function:
    if(set->nodes[position].occupied == 1) {
      if(setElemCompare(set->nodes[position].element, elem) == 0) {
        return SET_DUPLICATE;
      }
    }

should be:
    if(set->nodes[position].occupied == 1) {
      if(setElemCompare(set->nodes[position].element, elem) == true) {
        return SET_DUPLICATE;
      }
    }

and setElemCompare should return a bool.
Sorry for all the hassle, the set works as intended now.

This is one of the main reasons you should to have unit-tests for any non-trivial code. And code-reviews.
